# stream processing: combine jsons in a mem-constrained AWS Lambda and output a write stream to S3

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, streaming, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

In a mem-constrained environment (AWS Lambda) I'm trying to do the following:

- read jsons from a queue (AWS SQS). It's not known how many jsons exist on the queue
- consequently content-length isn't known beforehand
- each json is an array of objects
- combine these jsons in one big array (basically concatting the arrays)
- stream the combined json file to S3 while it's still being made.

This with the goal to keep mem usage low, even though the entire output file might end up being several GBs.

Although 'm pretty sure S3 can be streamed to using [S3 Multipart Upload](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-multipart-upload/) it's not clear if the entire setup would work. Any pointers, or streaming libraries that take the plumbing out highly appreciated.

Comment: I personally have never use it, but AWS Firehose sounds like it might be exactly what youre looking for.  Firehose allows you to stream data to a preconfigured destination.  More information [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/what-is-this-service.html)  
Also, are you also in control of what is writing to the queue? 
If so, I recommend taking a look at possibly using kinesis instead, since it is a supported event source.  With sqs you will have to set up some kind of polling (to the best of my knowledge)

Comment: Looked into kinesis, but I need a lot of different streams (or Topics in Apache Kafka parlance). This isn't available in Kinesis afaik. Other than that, yeah, Kinesis would be excellent.